# SICP - Lambda output

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

I defined the following procedure using Racket and inside the IDE Dr. Racket:

```
(define (random a b c x)
  (lambda (a b c x)
    (+ (* a (* x x))
       (* b x)
       c)))
```

As you might see, there is a lambda expression inside it. I tried calling:

```
(random 4 2 9 3)
```

And I got as an output:

```
#<procedure:...ercício-2.4.rkt:16:2>
```

I thought I would get 51.

Why does this happen? Why does the interpreter return the procedure and not result of the operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (proc-name args ...) body ...)
```

Makes a procedure and binds it to variable proc-name. Is an abbrivation for

```
(define proc-name 
  (lambda (args ...)
    body ...))
```

Where in this case `define` binds a variable to a value and that value happens to be a procedure. If you want to spell out your `random` it becomes:

```
(define random 
  (lambda (a b c x)
    (lambda (a b c x)
      (+ (* a (* x x)) (* b x) c))))
```

The outer is the procedure that takes arguments `a`, `b`, `c`, and `x` and the procedure returns another procedure that also takes arguments `a`, `b`, `c`, and `x` effectively shadowing the original bindings then does some expression on those. An example usage would be

```
((random #f #f #f #f) 4 2 9 3)
```

Since it's obvious your procedure was not suppose to return a procedure you should either use the short form on top:

```
(define (random a b c x)    
  (+ (* a (* x x)) (* b x) c))
```

Or the equivalent non sugared form:

```
(define random 
  (lambda (a b c x)    
    (+ (* a (* x x)) (* b x) c)))
```

It's common to have procedures return procedures as well as pass procedures as arguments that are used in procedures. Scheme has no idea if a variable binding is a procedure before it is supposed to call it with parentheses such that rookie mistakes like extra parentheses gives the strange error "application: (+ a b) not a procedure" if you try something like `((+ a b) 4)`

An example where return is a procedure can be partial application:

```
; makes a procedure that adds initial
(define (make-add initial)
  (lambda (v) (+ initial v))

(define add-10 (make-add 10))
(define add-3 (make-add 3))

(add-3  2) ; ==> 5
(add-10 2) ; ==> 12
```